# Are string literal created every time?

Tags: java, string, optimization, memory-management

So I was reading [orcale java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) and I read

> In this case, "Hello world!" is a string literal—a series of characters in your code that is enclosed in double quotes. Whenever it encounters a string literal in your code, the compiler creates a String object with its value

I want to make sure that am not creating random values all the time but this confused me, so does this mean that every time I use a string literal, a string object is created?

For example if I want to avoid creating new objects

```
String message = "am a NOT new string"
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{    
     someStringarray[i] = message;
}
```

is more efficient than

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
     someStringarray[i] = "am a new string EVERY time";
}
```

Comment: No, this will put the same literal every time in the array. It's logical -- it appears only _once_ in your source file after all, even though it's inside a loop. And there's string interning, too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+string+pool

Comment: Am wondering because in JavaScript, i store all of the strings I'll use beforehand in a array and later call them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, any instance of the same string literal always evaluates to the same object. In other words, in both of the above cases, there will only be one `String` object created, and the array will be filled in by having each entry reference that one string. There should not be an appreciable performance difference between the two.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So for the second one, I wouldnt have to worry about grabage collection because a bunch of strings wont be created then, just once?

Answer (score 0):

"Whenever" is as seen by the compiler, not as seen by your program. The compiler sees the string `"am a new string EVERY time"` exactly once, when it compiles line 3 of your program. So there's only one copy of it.

In general, you know you're creating a new object because you use the `new` keyword (or you call a function which does).

Comment: Does the compiler always do this or do I have to enable something?

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wanted to make sure since I cant figure out how to do the optimization stuff with the compiler like doing -java C or something like that

Answer (score 0):

All compile time string literals are interned(Java).
In the first case there is only one string in the memory and lots of pointers.
The second case is identical.

[Wikipedia - String Interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

Answer (score 0):

using it like you are at compile time the string table is created once at compile time and not repeated for each string, if you do create large arrays all pointing to the same object your are still using memory for the array itself. If you use StringBuffer type object or new() or take input from console then you would be using the heap and memory